# Pivot table query in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot

Is there a way to do a query in mysql with this scenario.

i have a table

```
group_name | cost_period | books_cost | others_cost 
group_A  |   1/01/2015  | 100         |  200
group_A  |   1/02/2015  | 56          |  86
group_A  |   1/01/2015  | 22          |  222
group_A  |   1/03/2015  | 30          |  40
group_B  |   1/02/2015  | 50          |  10
group_B  |   1/02/2015  | 45          |  10
group_B  |   1/01/2015  | 22          |  15
group_C  |   1/02/2015  | 45          |  20
```

and i want it to have this format after the query

```
                   JAN-2015  FEB-2015  MAR_2015  total
group_A 
sum of book cost     122       56         30       208
sum of others cost   422       86         40       548
group_B 
sum of book cost     22        95         0        117
sum of others cost   15        20         0        45
group_C
sum of book cost     0         45         0        45 
sum of others cost   0         20         0        20
```

is there a way this is possible by a query to avoid using a pivot tool once data is gathered? since jasper's crosstabs are not that flexible

thanks

Comment: I think the one you have proposed is not possible to do directly in the database, what could be possible is to generate two results one with book cost and the other one with others cost, where each column whould be month, and each row would be a group.
Is something like that acceptable for you?

Comment: hi @piotrgajow, thanks for the suggestion, but i think a pivot query can do this, i tried a few strategies but still missing some critical part for the grouping side. here's to hoping a pivot expert could help me.